# Incorrect usage of UPDATE, REPEAT and LIMIT on Stored Procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sql-update, limit, repeat

In my MySQL table I have this number of row :

```
mysql> SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS nrRow
FROM
    `doTable`;
+--------+
| nrRow  |
+--------+
| 334529 |
+--------+
1 row in set
```

Now I need update the column **doTableUO** on table **doTable** using **JOIN** with the table **doTableUser**.

I have tried this **Stored Procedure** without success because I have this error :

> Procedure execution failed 1221 - Incorrect usage of UPDATE and LIMIT

I thought use the **SP** using **LIMIT** syntax to avoid overloading the server.

If execute the SQL code in normal query I have this outout :

> [Err] 2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query

How I can solve this problem.

My code below.

```
BEGIN

REPEAT
UPDATE `doTable` jjj 
JOIN (
    SELECT
        `doTableUOUser`
    FROM
        `doTableUser`
    GROUP BY
        `doTableUOUser`
) AS kkk
SET jjj.doTableUO = kkk.doTableUOUser
WHERE
    jjj.doTableUO IS NULL
AND UPPER(jjj.doTableUO) = UPPER(
    kkk.doTableUOUser
) LIMIT 10000;
UNTIL ROW_COUNT() = 0 END REPEAT;

END
```

**Edit #2**
[image]

**Edit #1**

Simple SQL query :

```
UPDATE `doTable` jjj 
JOIN (
    SELECT
        `doTableUOUser`
    FROM
        `doTableUser`
    GROUP BY
        `doTableUOUser`
) AS kkk
SET jjj.doTableUO = kkk.doTableUOUser
WHERE
    jjj.doTableUO IS NULL
AND UPPER(jjj.doTableUO) = UPPER(
    kkk.doTableUOUser
);
```

Schema `doTable` :

```
CREATE TABLE `doTable` (
  `doTableUO` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `doTableUO` (`doTableUO`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Schema `doTableUser` :

```
CREATE TABLE `doTableUser` (
  `doTableUOUser` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `doTableUOUserNumber` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `doTableUOUser` (`doTableUOUser`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: As the error said you can't use update and limit like this. Why do you want to use a stored procedure? I don't see why you are not doing a 'simple' update.

Comment: @DanielE.Thank you for reply. I have tried with  'simple' update but I have error, please see my first question- `[Err] 2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

Comment: Can you edit and put the 'simple' query you used? And we will need a schema for the 2 tables.

Comment: @DanielE.Ok ready in first question, thank you

Comment: One last question, what are the values you want to update ? With your query it says to put null value to all null value.

Comment: why did you use limit? can you remove that please

Comment: @SandeepSudhakaran Thanks but remove LIMIT I have error `[Err] 2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

Comment: @ChevyMarkSunderland can you answer to my previous question ? In the image the explain show you don't have any  use of index.

Comment: @DanielE. `doTableUO` column is **Index - Normal - BTREE** on  `doTable`;  `doTableUOUser` is  **Index - Normal - BTREE** in  `doTableUser`

Answer (score 0):

From what i have understood you just want to put the same case in the 2 tables.

You can do this in one query like that :

```
UPDATE `doTable` dT
INNER JOIN `doTableUser` dTU
    ON COALESCE(UPPER(dT.doTableUO),'') = COALESCE(UPPER(dTU.doTableUOUser),'')
SET dT.doTableUO = dTU.doTableUOUser 
WHERE dt.doTableUO IS NOT NULL;
```

For more information about [COALESCE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_coalesce.asp)

Comment: Thank you for help but  I have `[Err] 2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query` :(

Comment: Try this and post the result in the question : `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `doTable` dT
INNER JOIN `doTableUser` dTU ON COALESCE(UPPER(dT.doTableUO),'') = COALESCE(UPPER(dTU.doTableUOUser),'') `

Comment: Ok, please see Img in **Edit #2** in my first question, thank you

Comment: `[Err] 2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query`